# Xcode 4 Adding Library

Tags: xcode, import, xcode4

anyone can explain in using the xcode 4 to add library by using

1. Link Binary With Library  (Build Phase tab)
2. Library Search Path (Build Settings)

If I add the **search path**, does that mean I do not need to **link binary with library** or vice versa

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can correct me if I am wrong or you have additional info to add in.

from my understanding now, The **Link Binary With Library** is defining which library will be using.

**Library Search Path** is to define where to look for those library defined in **Link Binary With Library** for those external libraries. The search is during runtime